# Exec stored procedure not working with JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch, sybase

I need to read data from both select and exec Sybase queries using JdbcCursorItemReader in Spring-Batch. While SELECT queries run perfectly, the Exec queries are running into the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
> Executing query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [exec
> proc_1]; SQL state
> [ZZZZZ]; error code [7773]; Execute cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is
> declared on a procedure which contains a non-SELECT or a SELECT with a
> COMPUTE clause. For the declaration of this cursor to be legal it
> should have a single SELECT statement without a COMPUTE clause.
>
> ; nested exception is com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Execute
> cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which contains
> a non-SELECT or a SELECT with a COMPUTE clause. For the declaration of
> this cursor to be legal it should have a single SELECT statement
> without a COMPUTE clause.
> ... 43 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Execute cursor
> 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which contains a
> non-SELECT or a SELECT with a COMPUTE clause. For the declaration of
> this cursor to be legal it should have a single SELECT statement
> without a COMPUTE clause.
>
> ... 45 common frames omitted

The code for the JdbcCursorItemReader is as follows:

```
JdbcCursorItemReader itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
ColumnMapRowMapper rowMapper = new ColumnMapRowMapper();
itemReader.setDataSource(getDataSource());
itemReader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
itemReader.setFetchSize(batchSize);
itemReader.setSql(dataSql); //datasql is passed Sybase query
```

Even after using StoredProcedureItemReader as suggested,
getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
> Executing stored procedure; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call
> ftsps_report(?, ?)}]; SQL state [ZZZZZ]; error code
> [7773]; Execute cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a
> procedure which contains a non-SELECT or a SELECT with a COMPUTE
> clause. For the declaration of this cursor to be legal it should have
> a single SELECT statement without a COMPUTE clause.
>
> ; nested exception is com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Execute
> cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which contains
> a non-SELECT or a SELECT with a COMPUTE clause. For the declaration of
> this cursor to be legal it should have a single SELECT statement
> without a COMPUTE clause.
>
> ```
>            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:90)
>
>            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
>
>            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
>
>            at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:226)
>
>            at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:406)
>
>            at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144)
>
>            ... 43 common frames omitted
> ```
>
> Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Execute cursor
> 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which contains a
> non-SELECT or a SELECT with a COMPUTE clause. For the declaration of
> this cursor to be legal it should have a single SELECT statement
> without a COMPUTE clause.
>
> ```
>            at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:4112)
>
>            at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:3229)
>
>            at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.getResultSetResult(Tds.java:3974)
>
>            at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsCursor.open(TdsCursor.java:333)
>
>            at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.sendRpc(SybCallableStatement.java:2032)
>
>            at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.execute(SybCallableStatement.java:241)
>
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
>            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
>            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>
>            at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>
>            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.execute(Unknown Source)
>
>            at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:210)
> ```

Have defined the StoredProcedureItemReader as follows:

```
StoredProcedureItemReader itemReader = new StoredProcedureItemReader();
ColumnMapRowMapper rowMapper = new ColumnMapRowMapper();
itemReader.setDataSource(getDataSource());
itemReader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
itemReader.setFetchSize(batchSize);
itemReader.setProcedureName(dataSql);
SqlParameter[] parameter = {new SqlParameter("date1", Types.DATE),new SqlParameter("date2", Types.DATE)};
itemReader.setParameters(parameter);
itemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(psSetter);
```

where psSetter setValues I have defined as follows:

```
ps.setDate(1, Date.ValueOf(paramList.get(0));
ps.setDate(2, Date.ValueOf(paramList.get(1));
```

I tried for few other stored procedures also and got similar issues.
Is it an error with the definition. I just want to define parameters by index preferably. Is there any straightforward way of doing so? Is it expecting the parameters in the stored procedure to be named date1/date2 specifically and failing because of that?

Answer (score 1):

For stored procedures, you need to use the `StoredProcedureItemReader` and not the `JdbcCursorItemReader`, something like:

```
@Bean
public StoredProcedureItemReader storedProcedureItemReader() {
    StoredProcedureItemReader reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader();
    reader.setProcedureName("yourProcedureName");
    // set other properties
    return reader;
}
```

Please refer to the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#StoredProcedureItemReader)  for more details.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud. Had modified it to StoredProcedureItemReader but still facing similar errors. Have added all details in the question. Could you kindly let me know if Im missing something here.

Comment: Are both the setParameters and setPreparedStatementSetter necessary? and how do they have to be linked together?

Comment: `Even after using StoredProcedureItemReader as suggested, getting the following error: For the declaration of this cursor to be legal it should have a single SELECT statement without a COMPUTE clause.` This error seems related to your stored procedure being rejected by Sybase and not related to parameters. I'm not sure Spring Batch can help at this level.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud. Will investigate this further. Just to confirm:
Are both setParameters and setPreparedStatementSetter necessary?
How can we pass indexed parameters to StoredProcedureItemReader??

Comment: According to [afterPropertiesSet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/e7ea16c9bc8bb3cbe174c8b190fff206b957e1bc/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/StoredProcedureItemReader.java#L143-L154), none of them is necessary,  only procedureName and rowMapper are mandatory properties.